# Use laspy to create las file from scratch without opening an existing las file first

Tags: lidar, las, laspy

I have found instructions for creating a las file by opening an existing file, modifying it, then re-saving it.

This re-uses the headers from the original file.

How do I create a new file from scratch without loading another in the first place?

I cannot see any documentation on the required format for the file, points, or headers.

I only need the bare minimum: x,y,z position for each point.

Here is how I assumed it might work:

```
import numpy as np
import laspy
import laspy.header
import laspy.file

points = []

#x,y,z values
points.append([0,0,10])
points.append([1,0,10])
points.append([2,0,11])

header = laspy.header.Header()
outFile = laspy.file.File("./output.las", mode = "w", header = header)
outFile.points = np.array(points)
outFile.close()
```

This fails with:

```
-> outFile.points = np.array(points)

/laspy/file.py
-> self._writer.set_points(new_points)

laspy/base.py
-> self.data_provider._pmap[:] = points[:]

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (3)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than setting the entire points array in one go, try setting each dimension in turn:

```py
import laspy

header = laspy.header.Header()
outfile = laspy.file.File("output.las", mode="w", header=header)
outfile.X = [1, 2, 3]
outfile.Y = [0, 0, 0]
outfile.Z = [10, 10, 11]
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! To get this working in other tools, I seem to also require: header.file_sig = 'LASF'

Comment: You're correct. I was using the latest version from Github, the `file_sig` bug was fixed in a post-1.2.5 commit: https://github.com/grantbrown/laspy/commit/0703dd9599bfd8283177ced80560f398b0a23c45

Answer (score 5):

The latest version of laspy will generate default file_sig = 'LASF', version_major = 1, version_minor = 2 and data_format_id = 0. However, **the header offset and scale have to be specified**. The following code (modified adamp's code) can generate output.las which can be read and then displayed using CloudCompare and QT Reader (The QT Reader needs minimum 4 points).

```
import laspy
import numpy as np

hdr = laspy.header.Header()

outfile = laspy.file.File("output.las", mode="w", header=hdr)
allx = np.array([1.000, 2.000, 3.000, 3.000]) # Four Points
ally = np.array([0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 3.000])
allz = np.array([10.000, 10.000, 11.000, 11.000])

xmin = np.floor(np.min(allx))
ymin = np.floor(np.min(ally))
zmin = np.floor(np.min(allz))

outfile.header.offset = [xmin,ymin,zmin]
outfile.header.scale = [0.001,0.001,0.001]

outfile.x = allx
outfile.y = ally
outfile.z = allz

outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using laspy version newer that 2.0.0, it can work by writing like this:

```
outfile = laspy.create(point_format=6)
points = np.array([x, y, z])
outfile.X = points[0]
outfile.Y = points[1]
outfile.Z = points[2]
outfile.write("outfile.las")
```

Answer (score 0):

Until I can get this working with laspy, I am successfully working around it using txt2las from LAStools:

```
cmd = str("wine ./bin/txt2las -o lidar.las -parse xyz -stdin -itxt")
cmd_parts = cmd.split(" ")

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
p = Popen(cmd_parts, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout_data = p.communicate(input='0,0,0\n1,2,3\n,4,5,6')[0]
```